# Recursive function : print statement before/after function call

Tags: java

Why is the output of these two codes different?

func 1: Prints the series in reverse as expected

```
public static void printSeriesInReverse(int n){
  if (n > 0){
     System.out.println(n);
     printSeriesInReverse(n-1);
  }
```

func 2: Prints series normal without reversing it.

```
public static void printSeriesInReverse(int n){
  if (n > 0){
     printSeriesInReverse(n-1);
     System.out.println(n);
}
```

Why does it make such a drastic difference whether the print statement or function call comes first?

Comment: What don't you understand about how the code works? Trace it out by hand.

Comment: I am learning recursion for the first time, I am new in programming so forgive me for not understanding simple "straightforward" stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a recursive function. Let's say you call it with `n=3`...

For the first case you would get:

```
printSeriesInReverse(3)
3 > 0 // YES
  prints 3
  printSeriesInReverse(2)
  2 > 0 // YES
    prints 2
    printSeriesInReverse(1)
    1 > 0 // YES
      prints 1
      printSeriesInReverse(0)
      0 > 0 // NO
      // End of recursion
```

Final output: `321`

For the second case you would get:

```
printSeriesInReverse(3)
3 > 0 // YES
  printSeriesInReverse(2)
  2 > 0 // YES
    printSeriesInReverse(1)
    1 > 0 // YES
      printSeriesInReverse(0)
      0 > 0 // NO
      // End of recursion
      prints 1
    prints 2
  prints 3
```

Final output: `123`

Comment: Now it is clear. I was struggling with the print statement in the second function. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Piyin, so does that mean the print statements get stacked in a queue elsewhere and are called after the recursion is done running?

Example:
printSeriesInReverse(3)
3 > 0 // YES **(print statement gets stacked)
  printSeriesInReverse(2)
  2 > 0 // YES **(print statement gets stacked)
    printSeriesInReverse(1)
    1 > 0 // YES **(print statement gets stacked)
      printSeriesInReverse(0)
      0 > 0 // NO
      // End of recursion
      prints 1
    prints 2
prints 3

Comment: No, what happens is the program only executes one line at a time, so when calling another function all the contents of that function will be executed and then the program will continue with the things below the function call. Think of it as if you were actually reading the code, is you "call" a function you should jump there and see what it does before coming back and reading the rest of the code